# The shape of Pringles potato chip

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Why the shape of Pringles potato chip is hyperbolic paraboloid?

[image: Pringles potato chip]

I found several articles that say the shape is hyperbolic paraboloid, but cannot find out why it is so. Does anyone have reasonable (and/or mathematical) answers?

Comment: I'd wager they thought the shape would be appealing.

Comment: I think this is a question about marketing, not mathematics.

Comment: Are you asking why the makers of Pringles chips chose this particular aesthetic, or how one can see that the chip pictured in your post is indeed a hyperbolic paraboloid?

Comment: @AWertheim I'm asking the former. In particular, I'm interested in what property of hyperbolic paraboloid forces the choice of shape. (e.g. For purpose X, negative curvature is efficient.)

Comment: I was here to do some math. Now, I feel hungry.

Comment: @orat. Guess it resists breaking up more than a flat or round chip after drying to  retain its original  shape. Also less breakage in packing or handling. If you step on a round metal object that size, it crushes. If on this shape it may cut the foot underside.

Comment: Aah, this question caused me a wrong answer at Quiz, got confused between pizza square boxes and it.

Comment: They do fit incredibly well into the package. The density, I'd wager, is ideal given the manufacturing variation in chips.

Comment: I found that "Pringles potato chips are designed using [supercomputing] capabilities -- to assess their aerodynamic features so that on the manufacturing line they don't go flying off the line" in [here](https://edition.cnn.com/2006/TECH/12/05/supercomputers/index.html).

Answer (score 13):

- The shape is self centering hence easy to stack up
- There is no trajectory that allows you to break up into predictable pieces, it's a saddle look it up, so increases the crunchy feeling hence that weird satisfaction. (homework: where do they find those extra long potatoes to make the fries?)
- It is relatively more feasible to manufacture the press block compared to other shapes. (Do you know the original size of a plastic cola bottle before it expands?)

But these are all true in hindsight; the real procedure is to do ridiculous amount of user study and then figure out why it works.

For example why washing machine doors are circular? Why toothbrush manufacturers want to have angles in fact you can easily rely on the technology known as your **elbow** etc.

Comment: Initially Pringles were a marketing disaster, and while targeted at young people they were in fact purchased by their grandparents because the reconstituted potato shapes remained crispy longer than standard chips/crisps made by slicing potatoes.

Answer (score 3):

I think pringles are shaped because they are designed to fit perfectly in your mouth .the roof of your mouth holds that shape and when you began to crunch your tongue fits perfectly under it to give you that awesome full taste of your chip

Comment: Wonder if it can be made mathematical at all! But as per the site guidelines, I suspect if this is an acceptable answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's called *minimal surface*. If you'll let a slice of bread drying it will naturally take this shape.

Comment: Well, then it's most definitely not a hyperbolic paraboloid.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for it might be something like this- 
Anything when given heat tries to minimize its surface energy. e.g. Bubble are formed because of surface tension force, to minimize stresses on surface of bubble, it forms spherical form, hence only stress acting on it will be normal pressure (Actually it is more precise to say static pressure). 
But potato chips are discs with an-isotropic behavior, contracts and expands with different rates when water is evaporated,  so it can neither form a spherical bubble to minimize energy nor any other closed shape because of high surface energy. Hence it ends up having highly distorted multidimensional geometry. But if you can develop a material which has different rated of contraction in only two direction, it might be possible to get a hyperbolic paraboloid.

Answer (score 1):

The hyperbolic paraboloid has an area, hence volume, that is greater than the chip would have if it was in the form of a flat disc in the same cylindrical package. So, the deceptively small package is cheaper to make than a cylinder that would accommodate a chip of the same volume in the form of a flat disc.
And the shape is kind of neat in a solid geometry sort of way.