# measuring the curvature of a pringle

Tags: differential-geometry, recreational-mathematics, hyperbolic-geometry

Assuming for the sake of argument that a pringle shaped potato chip has a constant negative curvature, (which according to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617610/88985 it is not )

see also picture at [The shape of Pringles potato chip](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617578/the-shape-of-pringles-potato-chip)

- How can we measure its curvature?

Assuming our ony measuring tool is an Vernier caliper ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calipers#Vernier_caliper )
(so we cannot measure along a surface)

- Can we still measure the curvature ?

and to end:

- Can we proof or disproof that a pringle has a constant curvature?

Comment: In principle, assuming constant curvature one option would be to triangulate the surface arbitrarily finely, use measurements of the triangle sides to estimate the area and geodesic curvature function of the boundary (within computable error bounds), and then apply the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem (also using the fact that a Pringle has no holes, I suppose).

Comment: Alternately, a symmetry argument shows that at the center of the Pringle, the principal directions coincide with the intersections of the Pringle with its planes of symmetry. Assuming you permit a construction using the caliper that lets us identify the center, we can then us it to estimate the principal curvatures there; recall that the product of these is the Gaussian curvature.